# Windows won't start and system repair can't fix it

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, bios, data-recovery

I get a black screen with the error 0xc00000e9.  Windows recovery can't fix my problem and system restore points aren't working.  I have:

- changed cables (power and SATA)
- put a different HD from another computer into the tower and Windows starts up just fine.

Anything left to try before reinstalling Windows?

Comment: What's indicated error message wise? What are you seeing that indicates the issue exactly, or what behavior do you observe in that respect?

Comment: @JUICED_IT  I get a black screen with the up error 0xc00000e9.

Comment: 0xc00000e9 is a hard drive i/o error, more than likely the hard drive is failing.

Comment: @Moab Yeah. I think the problem might be caused either by some malware or a recent windows update. I tried doing a system restore however the restore failed. When the computer is booted up it specifically gives the message, Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key

Comment: That does indicate it won't recognize the hard drive.

Comment: @TheMinecraftMan757 nope, its a hardware failure, the hard drive.

Comment: Boot to GParted and see if it sees the HD. You could always create a Clonezilla image and push it to another (new) HD and then see if it boots to Windows from the same Tower/enclosure. Maybe a Windows restore, ntfsfix, etc. would fix it to have Windows boot properly if data loss is your concern rather than a fresh install of the Windows OS. You mention that you may perhaps have another HD available so if you can wipe it and TRY, then maybe that'd fix your issue as easily as that. Just something QUICK I'd try when applicable.